# SQL Server 2008/2012: How to convert UTC time to local time given as a .NET timezone name?

Tags: sql-server, timezone

I am writing SQL reports for a configurable system. In this system, there are a number of 'sites' that may be all over the world, and each has its timezone stored as a name (using `System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` to turn it into a `TimeZoneInfo` object which will then be used to perform the conversion).

This means that the web interface (written in C#) can convert between UTC and site local time - but custom reports, written in SQL, can't. At least, none of us know a way to do it. We can execute arbitrary `SELECT` queries and even create and populate temporary tables in the context of a custom report, but can't alter the structure of tables that come as part of the system or add stuff to the overall database configuration.

It isn't a simple case of converting times to the end user's local time - a report may contain information about a number of sites, and the local time conversion would need to be correct for each.

We have a number of versions of the system - some use SQL Server 2008 and others 2012. Ideally we would like a solution that works under both, but failing that a 2012-specific solution may turn out to be acceptable.

Comment: Both SQL Server and .NET support DateTimeOffset. Use these types to avoid guessing or wrong conversions. It's similar to using Unicode to avoid codepage conversions

Comment: I've had a quick look at DateTimeOffset already.  But I can't see how it can help me with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: why not handle that issue in the presentation layer? what you call 'report' looks like as the dataset usually fed to a reporting engine and not as a true report. reporting services should be able to handle that issue easily using date formats and other engines as well, i suppose. do you have any reporting engine?

Comment: Because we aren't able to customise the presentation layer.  In order to implement a report, we just write SQL.  The system does some processing of the output - to add a filtering interface and suppress repeated values in some fields - but it doesn't do time zone conversion or even date/time formatting (so we already have to do this in the SQL, and so all the system receives to render is a string).